# Meteor delay find() so that I can access the object

Tags: mongodb, asynchronous, meteor

I've got a `findOne()` in a template helper in Meteor but I want to modify an array in the document before returning both the document as well as the updated array. When doing so I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'access' of undefined`. On the initial test it worked fine but I suspect that it's now failing because I'm trying to modify the document before `findOne()` completes. How do I get around this? Code below:

```
'curMatter': function() {
var curObj = Matters.findOne({_id:Session.get('editing_matter')});
var curAccess = _.without(curObj.access, Meteor.userId());
return { curMatter: curMatter, curAccess: curAccess };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Collection.findOne` completes before running code code that is after it (`var curAccess = _.without(curObj.access, Meteor.userId());` in your case).

The issue is that the document that you expect to get by this query is not available (yet) to the client, so `Matters.findOne({_id:Session.get('editing_matter')});` returns `undefined`.

So what it really means that your subscription is not ready, when the helper is run for the first time, and it fails.

What you can do is to check whether `curObj` is not `undefined` before accessing its property (i.e. `var curAccess = curObj && _.without(curObj.access, Meteor.userId());`

When the document becomes available to the client, the helper will be re-run, and you will get correct results then.

Here is your complete code:

```
'curMatter': function() {
    var curObj = Matters.findOne({_id:Session.get('editing_matter')});
    var curAccess = curObj && _.without(curObj.access, Meteor.userId());
    return { curMatter: curMatter, curAccess: curAccess };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use it as a cursor, they always seem to work better anyway.

```
Template['someTemplate'].helpers({
  curMatter: function () {
    return Matters.find({
      _id: Session.get('editing_matter')
    }).map(doc => Object.assign(doc, {
      curAccess: _.without(doc.access, Meteor.userId())
    }))
  }
});
```

Then you can use an `{{#each}}` in your template (even if it is always one item)